# How to set debug output query name using queryExecute

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'd like to find out if there is a way to set the debug output query name using queryExecute().

```
    <cfscript>
    qryTest = queryExecute('SELECT * FROM art', {}, {datasource="cfartgallery"});
    writeDump(var="#qryTest#");
    </cfscript>
```

Generates debug output like this:

[image]

UPDATE for CF 11u5, the debug output replaces "_queryname_var0" with "ExecuteQuery".  It looks like this variable name is safe from being over-written.

[image]

Comment: Fascinating. You are right. I'm going to file a bug report for this.

Comment: And... if you name a variable with that name, it gets overwritten. Nice. :\

Comment: @RaymondCamden thanks for filing the bug report.  I half expected that there was an option for the third argument (queryOptions) to account for the query variable name.  One of the reasons I asked is that the CF11 docs/wiki does not have any info for this argument!  "datasource", "result", and a few other options are listed in the examples, but it would be nice to have a complete list the options.  I assume things like "cachedwithin", "name", etc. may be valid options...  But only Adobe knows...  I'll ask another question.  I'm an aspiring point junky... ;)

Comment: If you make multiple calls to queryExecute(), _queryname_var0 is used each time.

Comment: Bug report comments say it was finally fixed in CF11 Update 5 (build 11,0,05,293506). Let us know if that is (hopefully) true ;-)

Comment: @Leigh has the bugbase system moved or something?  I get a ColdFusion error when I use the bugbase.adobe.com link.

Comment: @ScottJibben - No, the link below worked fine for me (earlier and just now). Maybe a temporary glitch?

Comment: @Leigh, strange it works for me with IE 11 and Chrome, but it comes up with an error with Firefox 38.0.5: "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members."

Comment: @ScottJibben - Weird. I'm using FF 38.0.5 too.  Are you logged in?  I was not.

Comment: @Leigh, I'm not sure.  I get this error even if I strip it down to just https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: @ScottJibben - ... That works fine for me too. That is why I was leaning towards differences like login status. Maybe the error is occurring while parsing login/session information? Since we know it is not browser version..

Comment: @Leigh, it started working for me now.  Not sure what it could have been.

Comment: What was the actual bug? Debug output keeps logging `ExecuteQuery` instead of the assigned variable name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer so I can maybe get some points. ;) It is a bug, pure and simple. I checked the Debugging template and the data is recorded with the incorrect name. I've filed a bug report here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3836702